# Add additional jars using PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have code to start a spark session

```
spark_session = SparkSession.builder.appName(app_name)
spark_session = spark_session.getOrCreate()
sc = spark_session.sparkContext
```

Now I want to dynamically be able to add jars and packages using PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS so I added an environment variable with the following value before I hit the code

```
--jars /usr/share/aws/redshift/jdbc/RedshiftJDBC4.jar --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:2.0.0,org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0,com.eclipsesource.minimal-json:minimal-json:0.9.4
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error: Missing application resource.
```

From looking online I know its because of the fact that I am explicitly passing jars and packages so I need to provide the path to my main jar file. But I am confused as to what that will be. I am just tring to run some code by starting a pyspark shell. I know the other way of passing these while starting the shell but my use case is such that I want it to be able to do it using the env variable and I have not been able to find the answers to this issue online